# How to list all LS commands in terminal and their functionalities?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ls

To put it bluntly I'm looking for a sort of "help" option that will show me what I can possibly do with a command, right from the terminal window, kind of like Python's `help()`.

A couple of questions:

1) Is there a way to see all the `ls` command options (or whatever they're called (see #3)) in the terminal window, that will show both the options and their descriptions? If so, how?

i.e. `ls -la : list long format including hidden files`

2) Is there an common option across every command to invoke that command's options and descriptions (i.e. `ls -?`)?

3) What are the letters or information followed by a dash called? `-a`, `-b`, `-c` etc. Are they options, commands, switches or something else? From my understanding `ls` is the command and "dash something" are options, but I've also seen the word switch thrown around and the entire string `ls -a` referred to as the command.

Comment: `list --help` (double dash). Those are options or switches. Switches is preferred for options without parameters.

Comment: Read the man page for the command: `man ls`. Arguments beginning with a dash are called *options*.

Comment: They are called "options", "switches", "flags", and probably other terms.  There is a surprising scarcity of uniformity.

Comment: All _GNU_ programs, and _some_ others, support `--help`. Linux distros normally use GNU versions of `ls` and other common utilities like `sed` `find` etc.; other Unix systems usually do not but the GNU versions often can be added and sometimes are accessed with `g` names like `gfind` `gsed` etc. `man` works on _most_ Unix systems, but some minimal configurations omit the man data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man ls` will give you everything you need to know about the command `ls`

This works with every commands obviously